# Calling Cython __cinit__ from Python __init__

Tags: python, cython, init

I have Cython class :

```
cdef class Blah:

   cdef __cinit__(self, arg): ...
```

then I want to inherit it as python class :

```
class Foo(Blah):
   def __init__(self,arg):
      super().__cinit__(arg)
```

how do I do that ? What are my options beside changing Foo to become Cython class ?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that. The `__cinit__` is only called by the C code, is it is the C level constructor.

Comment: can i write some Blah.__init__  ?

Comment: the `__init__` is the Python initializer and you should be able to call it.

Answer (score 2):

`__cinit__` is called automatically on class construction for the whole chain of Cython base classes. You don't need to call it yourself for derived classes (and in fact you can't). The `__cinit__` of a Cython base class is also called on Python classes that derive from it. This is the main advantage of `__cinit__` - it's guaranteed to be called exactly once so you can't put any initialization that *must* happen there.

`__init__` behaves exactly like Python - the `__init__` function for the most derived class is called, and then that function may or may not call `__init__` for their base classes.

As an example:

```
cdef class A:
    def __cinit__(self):
        ...

    def __init__(self):
        ...

cdef class B(A):
    def __cinit__(self):
        ...

    def __init__(self):
        pass

# in a different file, possibly
class C(B):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
```

You'll find the order of calls are

```
A.__cinit__
B.__cinit__
C.__init__
B.__init__  (because C.__init__ calls it)
not A.__init__  (because B.__init__ does not call it)
```

---

A common recommendation is:

- define `__cinit__` only if there's work that *must* be done to make the class valid (e.g. allocating memory in C/C++),
- define `__init__` for any "normal construction" work - essentially anything that won't lead to crash if it's skipped (accidentally or deliberately)

Comment: what about passing arguments ? super() ?

Comment: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#initialisation-methods-cinit-and-init - you can't change the arguments passed to it as you do down the class heirarchy. The recommendation is that you have `__cinit__` accept `*args` and `**kwds` so that derived classes can pass extra arguments

Comment: It's often a good idea to define both in a Cython class: `__cinit__` for any initialization that *must* be done (memory allocation, etc.) and `__init__` to act like a normal constructor. If there's no allocation that must be done then skip `__cinit__`